# How to enable bytecode enhancement for Hibernate with SBT?

Tags: hibernate, sbt, byte-code-enhancement

I've seen that Hibernate bytecode enhancement can be done very easily with a Maven plugin:
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-lazy-load-entity-properties-with-hibernate/

There's also a Gradle plugin for bytecode enhancement. 
Older versions of Hibernate had an ANT task.

But... how can I do it for an SBT project (Java Play, and Hibernate 5)?